# Will a commercial printer print my invitations using floral png's

Tags: adobe-indesign

I'm using InDesign for invitations. Can I use png florals in my designs? Will they print properly at a print company?

Comment: ***Welcome*** to **GD.SE** - Please look through [tour] to get a sense of who we are and what we’re about. Then look over [ask] and [answer] a question to see what makes a good query here, and how best to frame it. As currently framed, your question seems potentially off-topic because it's basically a vendor tech support question - you're likely to get a lot of "contact your vendor" responses. Perhaps a quick [edit] would help!

Answer (score 3):

First: Always consult with your vendor about how they require their file submissions. PNG format can be used for printing, and very often are used with perfectly acceptable results, but it may not be the most optimal format. I assume you want to take advantage of the PNG's transparency, which should be fine, but that comes with some baggage. There are three caveats to consider before using a PNG in a print layout:

1. **Resolution**: the PNG format is largely used for web graphics, so be
   sure that the PNGs you are using are sufficiently high resolution
   (optimally 300 effective resolution). Google "effective resolution
   indesign" if you aren't familiar with that term.
2. **Transparency**: Some printer's RIPs (the computer software/hardware
   that processes files for printing) may not process transparency
   well, especially if the layout also contains spot swatches.
3. **Gamut**: PNGs only support grayscale or RGB, not CMYK. Some printers
   require files to be submitted in CMYK only.

One way to mitigate many of the issues associated with PNGs in print layouts is to export using the PDF/X-4 standard.

Answer (score 1):

Ask them?

In general, if it is a simple digital print, you will be fine with whatever format or color mode.

For a more specific situation, when exporting your InDesign work to PDF you can convert the images to CMYK using a specific setup including the color profile.

For more advanced stuff, aka commercial print, where you need to print thousands of copies and you do not want surprises, you can convert your images prior to inserting them in InDesign.